# svn commit goes fine but there are no files on the server

Tags: svn

I have problem with svn. After create new project in netbeans IDE and svn on server i checkout the project and commit new local files, commit doesn't show errors everything goes fine but files are not there ? What can be the problem

Comment: Are you sure you committed the files? Did you add the files to SVN before?

Comment: Yes for both questions.

Comment: Use the svn command `svn list <REPO-URL>/<PATH>` to see whether the files are there or not.

Answer (score 1):

I am guessing you are looking for the files on the filesystem of the server?  The repository is like a database.  It is not something you can look at directly using the tools of the OS.  To see if the files are in the repository you need to use a svn client and run commands like log, ls, cat, checkout etc.

Answer (score 0):

If you're wondering why a separate working copy that lives on a server somewhere doesn't see new files, then you may just need to `svn update` that working copy.